# Subclipse on Ubuntu: 'Folder " does not exist remotely', Connection refused error

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, subclipse, javahl

So I have been banging my head against the wall for days on this one. When I initially set up Subclipse and first connected to my local SVN repo, everything worked great. Not sure what's changed since then, but now I keep getting errors when trying to access the repo.

In SVN Repository Exploring perspective, if I double-click on my repo I get a popup that says "Problem Occured - Folder " does not exist remotely". In my console, I get this error:

Connection refused
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://userid@localhost/home/userid/myrepository/java'
svn: Can't connect to host 'localhost': Connection refused

I have: 
Eclipse Juno
Ubuntu 12.04
Subversion 1.7.8

I initially started off with Subclipse 1.6 and JavaHL 1.6 but have since upgraded to Subclipse 1.8.3/JavaHL 1.7.8.1 in my efforts to get everything working again.
I even uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled, re-installed Subclipse and JavaHL, adding the JavaHL path to eclpise.ini... still can't access the repo.

I was accessing the repo locally in subclipse via "svn://userid@localhost/svn/home/userid/myrepository/java". I can access this repo locally from the command line just fine, and I can access this repo from another machine on my network using svn+ssh just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not a big fan of JavaHL and I never have had success with it in Eclipse / SVN. I might try SVNkit. I have used this and it works well.

Comment: I get the same errors when switching to SVNKit 1.7.8 in Windows->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN INterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repository is local, you should be using a URL like file:///home/userID/myrepository/java

To use the svn:// protocol you must have svnserve running.  The URL would then be something like:

svn://localhost/myrepository/java

When you use the svn+ssh:// protocol, the SSH daemon starts and launches svnserve in --tunnel mode within the SSH session.  So it does not need or use a normal svnserve daemon server that may be running.

FWIW, it would probably be a good idea to run svnserve, but that means you will also need to configure it.  But I would not use file:// URL using SVNKit.  If you use JavaHL exclusively, then it is fine, but I would not let SVNKit write directly to my repository.  Even though they do a great job testing and maintaining compatibility it is just easier to run svnserve and let SVNKit talk to it via the protocol.

Comment: Thanks a million, Mark. That was it. One of the things I tried was svn+ssh and file:///, but neither worked. After your post I tried again, this time discarding the location first and then adding it again using the svn+ssh and file:/// protocols and it worked. 
I think what happened was at some point I set up svn+ssh protocol for remote machines weeks after I had originally set up the local access with svnserve (which I hadn't used again until recently). This is a testament to why one should always take detailed notes when setting up new software... that or have a good memory.

Comment: btw, sorry I can't give you a +1. My rep appears to be too low :(

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I have no idea what you are talking about here.

I have installed Eclipse Kepler + Subclipse 1.6 + CollabNet Subversion/JavaHL 1.6. I can checkout my repo via "svn://...", but I cannot connect to it using a "https://..." repo address - if I enter that url, I am getting the above error.Since I am doing all this on a fresh OpenSUSE 13.1 installation and haven't done anything svn configuration related there (at least not manually and deliberately), I have no idea how to make Subclipse connect to my repo using the https url.

Comment: I'd say you entered bad URL.  When I entered the https:// URL you entered on other question into my Eclipse it worked fine for me.

Comment: I finally found out that some required tool was linked against an outdated SSL lib on my Linux distro, preventing me to connect to my svn repo via https. I tried to build it from the source, but then another dependency was outdated, and a dependencie's of that dependency source code I'd have needed for building wasn't available in the standard OpenSUSE repos, and I just couldn't be bothered to get the source just to find out I'd need to build even some more stuff. So I gave up on OpenSUSE (after years of using it) and switched to Linux Mint. Now everything is working fine there. Sigh.